# Try Ubuntu before installing - desktop screen problems

Tags: 14.04, boot, nvidia

I am trying to get the "Try Ubuntu before installing" option for several days, but have the same screen problem every time.

The desktop appears with the icons on the left and the keyboard shortcuts box in the center, but when I click on an icon the screen is jumbled.

I was going to post a picture of the jumbled screen but a flag came up and said that I had to have a reputation to post an image. The screen is a burgundy color with black dashes on the whole screen; sometimes with an inch yellow square that moves with the mouse.

I have tried Ubuntu 14.04.3 Desktop amd64 and 14.04.3 Desktop i386, both on DVD and USB with the same issue. I tried the nomodeset, acpi=off and nolapic boot parameter options : same result!

My computer:
Dell Inspiron 531s
AMD Athlon 64 X2 Dual Core 2.6 GHz
3 GB RAM
32 bit Vista
NVIDIA GeForce 6150SE nForce430

I assume that I have a regular BIOS since it looks like the ones I used when I was setting up hard drives in DOS many years ago.

I would like to install it as a dual boot solution if my hardware will support it.
Thank you for whatever advice you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that I was having a problem with the video driver and maybe resources when the Ubuntu desktop booted up and upon the first click of the mouse my screen was distorted. I finally found on-line the Ctrl+Alt+F2 command to get to the command line, so I didn't have to do a hard shut down. I downloaded the Xubuntu i386 image to try. I used the nomodeset and vga=771 command and was able to see and use the desktop with no scrambled screen in the try Xubuntu option. I then installed it to my hard drive. The screen was at an extremely low resolution but I found information how to load the proprietary nVidia driver and all is working well so far. Now I can start to learn Linux.

If there is a good book or pdf out there for learning the command line commands and what they mean that would be extremely helpful.

As a newbie to Linux, it is extremely difficult to follow help when you don't know what the commands or terminologies mean.